# Getting "use of undeclared type or module" when accessing impl module

Tags: rust

I have this module:

**src/adapters.rs**

```
use super::db::{init_connection, models};
use actix_web::Responder;
use diesel::r2d2::{ConnectionManager, Pool};
use diesel::MysqlConnection;

pub struct Basic {
   pool: Pool<ConnectionManager<MysqlConnection>>,
}

impl Basic {

    pub fn new() -> Basic {
        Basic {
            pool: init_connection().unwrap(),
        }
    }

    pub async fn admin_index(&self) -> impl Responder {
        "API Admin"
    }
}
```

and I'd like to call the instance method admin_index from the module:

**src/routes.rs**

like this:

```
use actix_web::{web, HttpResponse, Responder};
use super::adapters::Basic;

pub fn create(app: &mut web::ServiceConfig) {

    let basicAdapters = Basic::new();

    app
        .service(web::resource("/").to(|| HttpResponse::Ok().body("index")))
        .service(
            web::scope("/api")
                .service(
                    bweb::scope("/admin")
                        .route("/", web::get().to(basicAdapters::admin_index))
                )
}
```

but I keep getting:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type or module `basicAdapters`

.route("/", web::get().to(basicAdapters::admin_index))
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ use of undeclared type or module `basicAdapters`
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error message, because basicAdapters is obviously declared by

```
let basicAdapters = Basic::new();
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What kind of value do you expect `basicAdapters::admin_index` to be? A function of no arguments? A function of one argument? A future? An `impl Responder`?

Comment: That should not be of any concern at this point. The problem here is that the compiler claims that basicAdapters is undeclared despite its obvious declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`::` is a namespace resolution operator, and `basicAdapters` isn't a namespace.

To call a method on a value, use the `.` operator:

```
web::get().to(basicAdapters.admin_index())
```

Comment: You're are right. Thank you so much. The reason why I haven't considered your solution in the first place, was that the compiler was _not_ complaining about the method but about the 'basicAdapters' struct. At least, that's how I understood the error message. Thx again!